Questions regarding property in Manusmriti
I was studying 8.149 of Manusmriti, and it in this verse it degraded wife and slave to mere objects or wealth. My question is twofold, number one is it true a wife was considered property, or was a more accurate term to used responsability? Secondly, it states that the possession isn't lost due to adverse usage, so would this mean that in theory slavery was eternal for a dasa/dasi?
